# jsonResult with collectionname

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

Hi I would like to use the json collection from the code below in an angular repeater.
I need to give the collection a name but i dont know how

this is the code to generate the JSON

```
        public JsonResult GetProducts()
        {
             var result = db.Products.ToList();

             var list = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.None,   new JsonSerializerSettings(){ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore});

             return Json(list,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and this is the result

```
[{
"Category": {
    "ID": 4,
    "Name": "TEST"
},
"OrderDetails": [],
"ID": 10006,
"Description": "TEST",
"Name": "TEST",
"Price": 3.20,
"PictureUrl":"",
"CategoryId": 4,
"AddedToShop": "2016-12-11T14:52:57.677"
},
{
"Category": {
    "ID": 4,
    "Name": "TEST"
},
"OrderDetails": [],
"ID": 20005,
"Description": "TEST2",
"Name": "TEST2",
"Price": 3.20,
"PictureUrl":"",
"CategoryId": 4,
"AddedToShop": "2016-12-12T12:02:10.593"
}]
```

and I would like it to be like the code below so I can use the products tag to iterate .

```
{
"products": [{
"Category": {
    "ID": 4,
    "Name": "TEST"
},
"OrderDetails": [],
"ID": 10006,
"Description": "TEST",
"Name": "TEST",
"Price": 3.20,
"PictureUrl":"",
"CategoryId": 4,
"AddedToShop": "2016-12-11T14:52:57.677"
},
{
"Category": {
    "ID": 4,
    "Name": "TEST"
},
"OrderDetails": [],
"ID": 20005,
"Description": "TEST2",
"Name": "TEST2",
"Price": 3.20,
"PictureUrl":"",
"CategoryId": 4,
"AddedToShop": "2016-12-12T12:02:10.593"
}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using WebAPI controllers you don't need to send JsonResult, all you need to do is create a class and send it back to client:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public List<Product> Products { get; set; }    
}
```

And in your controller:

```
public MyClass Get() {
   return new MyClass {
      Products = db.Products.ToList()
   };        
}
```

OR:

Simply create your object and then pass it in the serializer:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject( { "products": result }, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings(){ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore})
```

Comment: thanks, the simple option worked , I'll try the first one too but for now this got me further thank you

Answer (score 0):

One solution for your problem is, define a seperate class and define a property for that class as either a collection or list of the type "db.Products"(Use the appropriate class name for this object as you have in your code) and when you serialize that object you will get it as you have asked for

```
class ProductList
{
public Collection<YourType> Products{get; set;}
}
```

OR

```
class ProductList
{
public List<YourType> Products{get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var list = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { products = result }, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
```